# Need help for a deeper understanding of BLE

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, stm32, bluenrg

I have to write a BLE application on an embedded device and there are some features where I'm not sure if BLE supports that or whether I've to create some wrapper around everything or if it's maybe not possible at all. The gerenal descriptions of Bluetooth and BLE I found around the internet usually only cover the overall functionality but don't go in too much detail. If this post gets too complex I'll split it up into different smaller ones.

I use the STM32 BlueNRG-MS chip

**1. Discoverability** (resolved)

---

The user has to be able to disable the BLE function in case there are several devices in reach. I see that there are functions `aci_gap_set_discoverable()` or `aci_gap_set_non_discoverable()` but altough I set it to not discoverable I can still see it in the LightBlue App on my mobile. How would I correctly disable the BLE functionality of a device to make sure no one can see it or connect to it?

*Update*: Okay that has been a mistake from my end, if I call the `aci_gap_set_non_discoverable()` function it is actually undiscoverable. So that's fine.

**2. Only accept connections of paired devices**

---

I'd like to achieve a behavior such that, if you have an unpaired phone you have to set the BLE device into a pairing mode in order to connect. If the phone has already been paired, the BLE device shall accept the connection request regardless of whether it's currently in pairing mode or not. Is this what the whitelist should be there for or do I have to do this manually by saving the address of the device after successful pairing? If whitelist is the right approach, I read that newer phones cause issues with whitelisting because they change their address on a regular basis, how can I handle this? That's actually where I thought I'm gonna work with the "discoverability".

**3. Automatically reconnect**

---

I'm not sure if this topic has to be handled on the BLE device or on the mobile phone. E.g. my phone is paired with my car's radio, so whenever the phone is in the car it automatically connects - how is this done? It's still the phone that acts as central device I assume?

Comment: So which programming language is this (C?) and which library is this?

Comment: It's C and I'm using the STM bluenrg library